# Excel VBA - Clear cells if box unchecked

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get VBA to clear cells if the end user unchecks a box. The entire process is, end user checks a box which allows them to enter data. But, once they uncheck the box, the data remains, but I would like for it to clear.

It's on a tab called Summary.

Here's the code I tried... which doesn't seem to be working:

```
Sub CheckBox_Click()
 
 With Sheets("Summary")
 If CheckBox3 = False Then
 .Range("C12:C13").Clear
 End If
 End With
 
End Sub
```

Seems simple, but I guess I'm missing something.

Edit: per my comment below, I need this to work on a 2nd checkbox (checkbox 4) that clears a separate area (cells C14 and C15) on the same worksheet.

Comment: Just a guess here... I'm thinking the sub should be `Sub CheckBox3_Click()` if the code is tied to `CheckBox3`? You may be testing another checkbox in your `If` statement than the one you intend.

Comment: I made your suggested change, but nothing happened. Also, there's another checkbox that I need to clear one other range of cells (checkbox 4 for cells C15 and 16), so I guess I need this to work on two checkboxes.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using active-x checkbox controllers on the sheet? If you right-click those and select "show code" it should make a `Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()` sub in the sheet code. Or is it a form control, which you'd access like `.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value` or something. And you just couple it with whatever macro.

Comment: They are both Form Control checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

### Clear a Range Via CheckBox

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ClearRange( _
        ByVal wsName As String, _
        ByVal rgAddress As String)
    Const Title As String = "Clear a Range"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    On Error GoTo WorksheetError
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo RangeError
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(rgAddress)
    On Error GoTo ClearRangeError
    rg.Clear
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
WorksheetError:
    MsgBox "The worksheet '" & wsName & "' doesn't exist.", _
        vbCritical, Title
    Resume ProcExit
RangeError:
    MsgBox "The range address '" & rgAddress & "' is invalid.", _
        vbCritical, Title
    Resume ProcExit
ClearRangeError:
    MsgBox "The range '" & rgAddress & "' was not cleared." & vbLf _
        & "(The worksheet may be protected.)", _
        vbCritical, Title
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Summary`**

- The following will work with `Active-X CheckBoxes`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
    If Not CheckBox3.Value Then
        ClearRange "Summary", "C12:C13"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()
    If Not CheckBox4.Value Then
        ClearRange "Summary", "C14:C15"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to put the code on the Summary tab's VBA, but nothing happened. I did change the "= ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code" to say "= Summary" and I still didn't get it to work. I'm sure I'm missing something... I'm very new to VBA. I tried putting the first block of code in a Module and the 2nd code in the Summary tab VBA, and that still didn't work. Again, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. And these are "Form Control" check boxes, not ActiveX.

Answer (score 0):

When using the form controls, the easiest way to make them run a macro when klicked is to assign said macro to them:

[image]

You can assign the same macro to both of them, but then you have to check which Checkbox called the macro. And then decide what it's supposed to do. Which we can do with `Application.Caller`. Or you could technically loop through all checkboxes, and apply the action to all unchecked boxes.

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFormat.Value
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
Debug.Print Application.Caller
```

Example of ways to return the value of the clicked checkbox, Name, and other kind of name...

Then you could do something like:

```
If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFormat.Value = -4146 Then
    If Application.Caller = "CheckBox 3" Then
        Range("C12:C13").Clear
    ElseIf Application.Caller = "CheckBox 4" Then
        Range("C14:C15").Clear
    End If
End If
```

Just make sure you use the correct propery to refer to the checkbox, so that your name and the value used matches.

You can also loop through all the Checkboxes and look at their properties:

```
For Each x In Sheets("Summary").CheckBoxes
        Debug.Print "Name:"; x.Name & " - Caption: " & x.Caption & " - Value: " & x.Value
Next x
```

I didn't bother with specifying the sheet on the ranges, because of the change happening in the same sheet, and it's tricky to click boxes on a not active sheet.